# Entity Framework 6.1.3

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have a project that looks up distinct orders from the database. It then creates a string of CustomerNumbers from a field in the returned orders. Then it filters the orders based on the CustomerNumbers. The issue is it only ever returns 2 customers when there should be 10. I did return a count of all customers & that also only returns 2 customers. There are a total of 667K+ customers in the database. I tried uninstalling the EF nuget package & reinstalling. I checked to make sure the repositories I have setup aren't filtering anything in anyway. I'm stuck & under the gun right. Any help would be great. Also any refactoring suggestions or EF changes are welcome too. Thanks!

```
var count = dbCustomer.Records.Count();

var orders = dbOrders.Records.ToList();
data.Orders = orders;

var orderCustomerNumbers = data.Orders.Select(o => oMeta15).Distinct().ToList();
var orderNumbers = data.Orders.Select(o => o.OrderNumber.ToLower()).ToList();

data.Customers = dbCustomer.Records.Where(c => orderCustomerNumbers.Contains(c.CustomerNumber)).To.List();
data.Payments = dbPayment.Records.Where(p => orderCustomerNumbers.Contains(p.OrderNumber.ToLower())).ToList();
data.Products = dbProducts.Records.Tolist();
```

Comment: Also, I spun up a quick console app and did code first against the database. I can get all customers in that app.

Comment: Is it possible to share relevant code so people can see where you may have gone wrong? This will help get more responses.

Comment: @gt5193 It would also help to include the code snippet in the question rather than using an image. You can format the code with 4 leading spaces.

Comment: @gt5193 What is `o.Meta15`? Are you sure that's your customer number? Also, wouldn't it be better to use `== c.CustomerNumber` instead of `Contains(c.CustomerNumber)`?

Comment: Sorry. I'm a SO newb. I'll get that code up ASAP =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not getting more details out, but I did fix the issue. Originally I had issues getting the data into the database using the app(EF). To get around the issue and keep moving forward I used SSMS to import the data. Since I didn't use the app(EF), to import the data the Discriminator column was never filled in with data. Therefore the only two rows that were being returned were the rows with the correct value in the Discriminator column. After running a quick SQL statement to update all the rows with the correct Discriminator value everything is working fine now.